# Web Audio API, get getByteTimeDomainData for left / right channel in two arrays.

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I'm currently trying to create an audio visualisation using an web audio api, namely I'm attempting to produce lissajou figures from a given audio source.

I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706651/creating-a-vectorscope-in-javascript-using-the-web-audio-api), but I'm missing some preconditions. How can I get the time domain data for the left / right channels? Currently it seems I'm only getting the merged data.

Any help or hint would be much appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
  var audioElement = document.getElementById('audioElement');
  var audioSrc = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);
  var analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();

  // Bind analyser to media element source.
  audioSrc.connect(analyser);
  audioSrc.connect(audioCtx.destination);

  //var timeDomainData = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
  var timeDomainData = new Uint8Array(200);

  // loop and update time domain data array.
  function renderChart() {
     requestAnimationFrame(renderChart);

     // Copy frequency data to timeDomainData array.
     analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(timeDomainData);

     // debugging: print to console
     console.log(timeDomainData);

  }

  // Run the loop
  renderChart();

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The observation is correct, the waveform is the down-mixed result. From the [current spec](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#widl-AnalyserNode-getByteTimeDomainData-void-Uint8Array-array) (my emphasis):

> Copies the current **down-mixed** time-domain (waveform) data into the
>   passed unsigned byte array. [...]

To get around this you could use a channel splitter (`createChannelSplitter()`) and assign each channel to two separate analyzer nodes.

For more details on `createChannelSplitter()` see **[this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createChannelSplitter)**.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the provided links and the hint to a solution, those answers my question indeed.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve that by using the [`StereoPannerNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StereoPannerNode/StereoPannerNode) `pan` option:

> A floating point number in the range [-1,1] indicating the position of
> an AudioNode in an output image. The value -1 represents full left and
> 1 represents full right. The default value is 0.

---

**Web-radio with 2 channels stereo VU Meters**

On the following demo, the BBC world radio get split into two left and right channels. Those channels are then routed into their own analyzers, who feeds the value for the progress bars. The looping is done using animation frames and timers.

```js
const ctx = new AudioContext();
const audioSrc = ctx.createMediaElementSource(player);
const analyserL = ctx.createAnalyser();
const analyserR = ctx.createAnalyser();
let job, origin = new Date().getTime();
const L = new StereoPannerNode(ctx, {pan: -1});
const R = new StereoPannerNode(ctx, {pan: 1});

audioSrc.connect(analyserL);
audioSrc.connect(analyserR);
audioSrc.connect(ctx.destination);

analyserL.fftSize = 32;
const bufferLengthL = analyserL.frequencyBinCount;
const frequencyDataL = new Float32Array(bufferLengthL);

analyserR.fftSize = 32;
const bufferLengthR = analyserR.frequencyBinCount;
const frequencyDataR = new Float32Array(bufferLengthR);

let i = 0;
const timer = () => {
  if (new Date().getTime() - i > origin){
   analyserL.getFloatFrequencyData(frequencyDataL);
   analyserR.getFloatFrequencyData(frequencyDataR);
   let vL = 100 - (Object. values(frequencyDataL).reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0) * -0.03)
   let vR = 100 - (Object. values(frequencyDataR).reduce((a,b) => a + b, 0) * -0.03)
   VUL.value = ~~vL
   VUR.value = ~~vR
   i = i + 41 // 24 FPS
   job = requestAnimationFrame(timer)
  } else if (job !== null){
      requestAnimationFrame(timer)
  }
}

/* Start looping ------------------------*/
requestAnimationFrame(timer)
```

```html
<audio id="player" controls crossorigin="anonymous" autoplay src="https://stream.live.vc.bbcmedia.co.uk/bbc_world_service"></audio>
<br>
L <progress id="VUL" max="100" value="0"></progress>
<br>
R <progress id="VUR" max="100" value="0"></progress>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StereoPannerNode/StereoPannerNode